# InvalidOperationException: ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters:

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm trying to code an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) for a local ASP.NET page.

Reading the Help files on MSDN always leave me scratching my head, wondering what exactly they might be implying. For example, I am not sure what my [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.typename.aspx) should be (though that link has an interesting example).

Once I get the basics to work, I will venture into deeper waters.

The first line of my *.aspx file contains my definitions:

```
<%@ Page Title="Reporter" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/local.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reporter.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="AcpServiceNS.Reporter" %>
```

In this page, I have TextBox controls named `txtStartDate` and `txtEndDate` and a number of DropDownList controls named `ddlStartTime`, `ddlEndTime`, `ddlAction`, `ddlFilter1`, and `ddlFilter2`.

I also have the following [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsReport" runat="server"
     SelectMethod="GetData"
     TypeName="System.Data.DataTable"
     ConvertNullToDBNull="True" >
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtStartDate" Name="startDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStartTime" Name="startTime" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtEndDate" Name="endDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEndTime" Name="endTime" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlAction" Name="action1" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlFilter1" Name="filter1" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlFilter2" Name="filter2" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

A [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control is going to be on the *.aspx page, and will be used to display the data:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Font-Size="Small" PageSize="30" Width="100%"
  OnRowDataBound="Report_RowDataBound"
  OnRowCommand="Report_RowCommand"
  DataKeyNames="Op_ID,Serial_Number,Date_Time,Test_Result"
  DataSourceID="dsReport"
  runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Op_ID" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbOp_ID" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Op_ID" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial_Number" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSerial_Number" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Serial_Number" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Time" HeaderText="Date_Time" SortExpression="Date_Time" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Test_Result" HeaderText="Test_Result" SortExpression="Test_Result" HeaderStyle-Width="40%" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

To get this to load an empty dataset, I have created this simple stub in my codebehind:

```
namespace AcpServiceNS {

  public partial class Reporter : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    protected static DataTable GetData(string startDate, string startTime, string endDate, string endTime,
      string action1, string filter1, string filter2) {
      var table = new DataTable();
      table.Columns.Add("Op_ID", typeof(string));
      table.Columns.Add("Serial_Number", typeof(string));
      table.Columns.Add("Date_Time", typeof(DateTime));
      table.Columns.Add("Test_Result", typeof(string));
      return table;
    }

  }

}
```

Yes! All that is above is basically a Table Definition, but it should be enough to start my *.aspx page.

When I try to run this, I get the following Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ObjectDataSource 'dsReport' could not find a non-generic method 'GetData' that has parameters: startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime, action1, filter1, filter2.

It appears that I have spelled and cased all of the parameters correctly, so what have I done wrong? Is [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.typename.aspx) used incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx), I would say yes you're using `TypeName` wrong.  In the MSDN article, it refers to the class which hosts the method, not the return type of the method.

Try changing `TypeName="System.Data.DataTable"` to `TypeName="AcpServiceNS.Reporter"`

Comment: +1. Thanks for that suggestion. Now I get this: `ObjectDataSource 'dsReport' could not find a non-generic method 'Reporter.GetData' that has parameters: startDate, startTime, endDate, endTime, action1, filter1, filter2.` Confusing.

Comment: You're going to kick yourself ;)  Try making the method `public`

Comment: I tried setting the method to `public`, but that didn't help. What seemed to solve the issue (and why I can't explain) was going into the designer and selecting my items from the Wizard. My **ObjectDataSource** looks exactly like it did with the `TypeName` you pointed out above, but by doing it in the designer instead of the HTML, it worked. So, you were right! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to create an ObjectDataSource?  It just seems very old-school.

Comment: Huh? I thought I was learning the new way. If this stuff is old, what is new?

Comment: For Asp.net classic, it would be binding the datagrid to objects.  ie.  `datagrid1.DataSource = myList; datagrid1.Databind();`  Even further than that, you'd want to look into MVC3 or MVC4 and entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

Your typename must show your service type like below;

```
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsPoint" runat="server" SortParameterName="sortColumns" EnablePaging="True" 
                    StartRowIndexParameterName="startRecord" MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRecords"
                    SelectCountMethod="GetCategoryPoints" SelectMethod="GetCategoryPointsByFilters" 
                    TypeName="EvaluationAssistt.Service.Services.EvaluationReportingService" 
                    UpdateMethod="GetCategoryPointsByFilters">
```

Care about here: `TypeName="EvaluationAssistt.Service.Services.EvaluationReportingService"` 
where is your service method write here the path (such as strong name;-)